# After publish application, icon is not changing

Tags: c#, icons, taskbar

I am changing my icon according to performance with following commands.

```
this.Icon = Properties.Resources.high;   
this.Icon = Properties.Resources.low;   
this.Icon = Properties.Resources.normal;
```

If I run the program exe file, it is working, However after I publish application, setup it to my computer and then run it, icon stays always same. It is not being updated. How can I fix this problem?

P.S. during application runs, when I right click at taskbar icon, pin it from taskbar and unpin from taskbar, application is working like exe file, icon is changing. But I can't tell to customers do this process everytime.

Comment: Whate is `this` referencing? A tray icon?

Comment: this is referencing form, It doesn't matter if I use it or not.

Comment: The form is part of the assemlby that is compiled. You can't change it. The reason it works for you in test is because you are recompiling everytime. Things change a little when you compile for the release.

Comment: yes I thought as you, however after right click to icon at taskbar, pin it from taskbar and unpin from taskbar, why it behaves same with exe file. this really confused me...

Comment: Interesting... I'm not sure whats going on. I'll take a look at creating a demo project like yours and see if I can figure it out tomorrow.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: I created a demo project that has three buttons and each one sets the form icon to one of three icons that I've imported. I didn't have any trouble whatsoever. I posted an answer with my code the I used. I'd say its something else with your code that's causing it not to work. If you could post more or all of your code I'd be happy to look into it further. It's also possible that the way your publishing your application could be causing it. How are you publishing it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample that does what I think your wanting:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Resources;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Icon = Properties.Resources.icon;


            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Icon = Properties.Resources.image;
            }

            private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Icon = Properties.Resources.ICO_Logo;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, however you can try to publish your application and then run it from start -> all programs. your icon on taskbar won't be changed. I am not sure this problem may occur just with windows 7 which I am trying now.

Comment: I'm running Win8 and there's no problem. It could be Win7 or the way you are publishing your application. The only thing that I can suggest to you now, is try and instead of using Properties.Resources.{file name}, actually provide a path to the file like "C:\testicon.ico". If it works, then it would indicate a problem with way the application is being published. Sorry I can't be of more help to you!